# A regular expression parsing library in C

Tags: performance, c, parsing, regex, library

I've created a regular expression (regex) parsing library in C, and would like some feedback on it.  Speed is really important to me, but any and all suggestions are acceptable.

```
#include <ctype.h>

static int regex_matchHere(const char *regex, char *s, int *len);
static int regex_matchGroup(int c, int group);
static int regex_matchQuantity(int quant, int c, const char *regex, char *s, int *len);

int regex_match(const char *regex, char *s, int *len)
{
    char *p = s;

    /* force match from the beginning of the string */
    if (regex[0] == '^') return (regex_matchHere(regex + 1, s, len) ? 0 : -1);

    /* iterate the string to find matching position */
    do
    {
        *len = 0;
        if (regex_matchHere(regex, p, len)) return (int)(p - s);
    } while (*p++ != '\0');
    return -1;
}

static int regex_matchHere(const char *regex, char *s, int *len)
{
    int c = regex[0];

    if (regex[0] == '\0') return 1; /* end of regex = full match */
    else if (regex[0] == '$' && regex[1] == '\0') return (*s == '\0'); /* check end of string */
    else if (regex[0] == '\\' && regex[1] != '\0') /* check escaped symbol */
    {
        c = regex[1];
        if (c != '^' && c != '$' && c != '\\' && c != '+' && c != '*' && c != '-' && c != '?') c = c | 0x100;
        regex = regex + 1;
    }
    /* check for special operators *,+,?,- */
    if (regex[1] == '*' || regex[1] == '+' || regex[1] == '-' || regex[1] == '?') return regex_matchQuantity(regex[1], c, regex+2, s, len);
    else if (*s != '\0' && regex_matchGroup(*s, c))
    {
        *len = *len + 1;
        return regex_matchHere(regex+1, s+1, len);
    }
    return 0;
}

static int regex_matchGroup(int c, int group)
{
    if ((group & 0xff) == '.') group ^= 0x100;
    if (group < 0x100) return c == group; /* a single char */
    /* a meta char, like \d, ... */
    switch (group & 0xff)
    {
        case 'd': return isdigit(c);
        case 's': return isspace(c);
        case 'D': return !isdigit(c);
        case 'S': return !isspace(c);
        case '.': return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static int regex_matchQuantity(int quant, int c, const char *regex, char *s, int *len)
{
    if (quant == '?')
    {
        if (regex_matchGroup(*s, c))
        {
            *len = *len + 1;
            s = s + 1;
        }
        return regex_matchHere(regex, s, len);
    }

    if (quant == '+' || quant == '*') /* match as much as possible */
    {
        char *p;
        for (p = s; *p != '\0' && regex_matchGroup(*p, c); p++) *len = *len + 1;
        if (quant == '+' && p == s) return 0;
        do
        {
            if (regex_matchHere(regex, p, len)) return 1;
            *len = *len - 1;
        } while (p-- > s);
    }
    else if (quant == '-') /* match as little as possible */
    {
        do
        {
            if (regex_matchHere(regex, s, len)) return 1;
            *len = *len + 1;
        } while (*s != '\0' && regex_matchGroup(*s++, c));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although it *can* be divined from the code, it wouldn't hurt to explicitly state the exact sort of regular expressions this is intended to parse/match.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### What you did well

The code seems clean and logically organized.  I like your 0x100-bit hack to indicate special characters.  You could make that convention more obvious in the comments, though.

#### What you could improve on

1. The return value of `regex_match()` is weird.  I'd like it to return a non-zero value if the match succeeded, and a zero value if the match failed, so that I can call it like this:

   ```
   if (regex_match(...)) {
       // Do stuff for successful match
   } else {
       // Do stuff for failed match
   }
   ```

   Trying to return the position of the match just leads to confusion, reminiscent of the way PHP's [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) returns 0 to indicate a successful match at the beginning of the subject (but `FALSE` to indicate a non-match).  You don't want to be like PHP, do you?

   I suggest that the signature for `regex_match()` should look like this:

   ```
   /**
    * Returns 1 if matched, 0 if not matched.
    *
    * Pass a pointer to a match_result if you care to find out the
    * details of the match (its length, position, and possibly other
    * information supported in the future, such as parenthesized
    * capture groups), or pass a NULL if you don't care about the details.
    */
   int regex_match(const char *regex, const char *subject, struct match_result *result);
   ```

   Alternatively, return a pointer to a new `struct match_result` if the match succeeded.  The caller would have to `free()` the result later, though, so I don't like it as much.
2. Regular expressions often include modifier flags, such as a case-insensitive flag or a continue-searching-where-the-previous-match-ended flag.  You might want to plan your interfaces accordingly.  (To support the latter, the `struct match_result*` would probably become an in-out parameter rather than an out-parameter.)
3. For performance, regular expressions are frequently compiled into an automaton.  You interpret the regular expressions as you go.  You may wish design the library's interface to have a `regex_compile()` function that transforms the expression into a struct that is meaningful to your library but opaque to the user.  For now, the "compilation" could just be the identity transformation; you can enhance it later when the need for better performance arises or when you enhance the feature set of the regular expressions.
4. The function name `regex_matchGroup()` confuses me.  "Group" implies something like parentheses, I think.  `regex_matchAtom()` might be a more appropriate name.
5. You *need* unit tests!

Comment: This is a nice review, except for the part about the return value – returning an index an expecting the caller to do `if (0 <= regex_match(...))` is perfectly natural. The problem with PHP is that it took a C-ish idiom and messed it up by returning `false` instead of `-1`, but that does not discredit the original idiom.